# grouped category search

Tags: categories, zoo-visitor, filter

I have a zoo visitor channel for all my members.  My zoo visitor has multiple category groups.  I am trying to create a category drop filter menu to filter the members by category.  In the drop menu I need each group name displayed and then all the categories:

ie:
Filter by Category:

--Category Name A--

Category 1

Category 2

--Category Name B--

Category 1

Category 2

The 2 categories I am using right now are group ID 39 and 41

```
<form name="catmenu" action="">
  <select name="selcat" onchange="location=document.catmenu.selcat.options[document.catmenu.selcat.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value="">Filter by Category</option>
  {exp:channel:categories cache="yes" refresh="60" channel="zoo_visitor" disable="category_fields" style="linear"}
{if parent_id == '39'}{if count != '1'}</optgroup>{/if}<optgroup label="{category_name}">{/if}
{if parent_id != '39'}<option value="{path='home/directory'}">{category_name}</option>{/if}
  {/exp:channel:categories}
 </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried to help you, but I can't understand one thing. Are 39 and 41 categories or category groups?

Comment: THEY ARE CAT GROUPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need addons for this. Try to use addons just when you really need them.

```
<form name="catmenu" action="">
  <select name="selcat" onchange="location=document.catmenu.selcat.options[document.catmenu.selcat.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value="">Filter by Category</option>
    <optgroup label="group 39">
    {exp:channel:categories cache="yes" refresh="60" channel="zoo_visitor" disable="category_fields" style="linear" category_group="39" show_empty="no"}
        <option value="{path='home/directory'}">{category_name}</option>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="group 41">
    {exp:channel:categories cache="yes" refresh="60" channel="zoo_visitor" disable="category_fields" style="linear" category_group="41" show_empty="no"}
        <option value="{path='home/directory'}">{category_name}</option>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
    </optgroup>
 </select>
</form>
```

Comment: another strange occurance.  When I select a category the results page display all entries, not the ones dynamic to the segment_3 category:

http://domain.com/index.php/directory/category/cat_name
{exp:zoo_visitor:members limit="99" member_group="5" orderby="random" dynamic="yes"}
 <h2>{visitor:member_firstname} {visitor:member_lastname}</h2>
  {/exp:zoo_visitor:members}

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is related to Zoo Visitor, not directly to channel:categories. Since I never used Zoo Visitor, I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

GWCode categories seems to be of some help.  Testing this right now:

```
<form name="catmenu" action="">
  <select name="selcat" onchange="location=document.catmenu.selcat.options[document.catmenu.selcat.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value="">Filter by Riding</option>
<optgroup label="Group 1">
{exp:gwcode_categories channel="zoo_visitor" entry_count="yes" group_id="39" excl_group_id="41" show_empty="no" style="linear"}
    <option value="{path="examplepath/{cat_url_title}"}">{cat_name} ({entry_count})</option> 
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
<optgroup label="Group 2">
{exp:gwcode_categories channel="zoo_visitor" entry_count="yes" group_id="41" excl_group_id="39" show_empty="no" style="linear"}
    <option value="{path="examplepath/{cat_url_title}"}">{cat_name} ({entry_count})</option>
{/exp:gwcode_categories}

 </select>
</form>
```